# Bash script with path name failing

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I'm using the following Bash script but getting the following silly error:

```
Fixing perms on /Volumes/Volume-B/IMAGES/Prostock scans/
chmod: Failed to set ACL on file '/Volumes/Volume-B/IMAGES/Prostock': No such file or directory
chmod: Failed to set ACL on file 'scans/': No such file or directory
chmod: Unknown tag type 'inherited'
```

Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin export PATH
DEST=/Volumes/Volume-B/IMAGES/Prostock\ scans/

echo Fixing perms on $DEST
chmod -R +a "user:administrator allow list,add_file,search,delete,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit" $DEST 

chmod -R +a "user:icadmin inherited allow list,add_file,search,delete,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,writesecurity,chown,file_inherit,directory_inherit" $DEST

echo Done!
```

Note I've wrapped $DEST in single and double quotes with and without the backslash after "Prostock" and get same error.

Suggestions most appreciated!

Dan

Comment: set double quotes around the chmod $DESTs

Comment: Once you correct the single outstanding bug (lack of quotes around `$DEST`, which should be `"$DEST"`... or, if you were following convention and making non-environment variables lowercase, `"$dest"`), this becomes a question about OS X's chmod, not about bash.

Comment: ...to be clear -- the "No such file or directory" errors (of which you have two) are caused by the lack of quotes; the "unknown tag type" is a question about OS X's version of chmod, as most operating systems don't support ACLs through the chmod command at all, instead using tools such as `satfacl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried putting double quotes around the `$DEST` variable?

```
chmod -R +a "user:icadmin inherited allow...." "$DEST"
```

Comment: Oops, just saw your comment about double quotes...

Comment: Actually, putting quotes around "$DEST" should work on the chmod command